# Execute Javascript in python

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7, pyv8

I have JS script that gets as a parameter another JS and unpack it (from eval(function) packers).
I tried to run it using PyExecJs but it raise me errors like `execjs.RuntimeError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;`

I tried to use PyV8 but I got a issues with install it..
Does anybody know another simple way to run JS through Python?

Comment: Please, provide both scripts.

Comment: You need to refer this thread
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136319/executing-javascript-from-python

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can help [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html). This is not the best solution. Maybe you have a bug script? You can lay out a script?