# Missing html in response using python requests and beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

When I view the page source in my browser, the html I am after appears there. However, when I make a requests using python requests the html doesn't appear.

The url I'm trying to scrape is http://dota2lounge.com/match?m=13362, and the specific html I am after in the page is.

```
<div class="full">
    <a class="button" onclick="ChoseEvent(13362,'Whole Match',false)">Match</a>
    <a class="button" onclick="ChoseEvent(13392,'1st Game','1462327200')">1st Game</a>
    <a class="button" onclick="ChoseEvent(13424,'2nd Game','1462327200')">2nd Game</a>
    <br><div id="toma" class="full" style="background: #444;line-height: 2.5rem;border: 1px solid #333;text-align: center;">Whole Match</div>
</div>
```

I'd like to get the 'onclick' values of the buttons. So far I've tried:

```
r = requests.get('http://dota2lounge.com/match?m=13268')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
buttons = soup.find_all('a', class_='button')
```

Which doesn't work.

```
r.content
```

Doesn't appear to show the html either.

Comment: Try ```soup.find_all('a', 'button')```. Btw sounds like you have a typo in the param class: ```soup.find_all('a', class='button')```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the elements you want are being added by javascript that isn't being run when you make the request in python. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136319/executing-javascript-from-python).

If you're just scraping this once (i.e. you just want the data and you're not trying to build a bot to play the game for you), the quickest option is often to just create a .htm file containing only links to every page you want to scrape (put each link in an `<a>` tag, you don't even need text). Then you can use a tool like [downthemall](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/) in firefox to save a local copy of every page with the proper formatting.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
        print link.get('onclick')
```

Comment: Thanks but I tried your suggested parser and that didn't work. If I look into the text from the Request response I still can't see the html there. Are there any reasons it would be rendered in my browser but not in the Python Request?

Comment: i didn't find your html section in source code and try this code on http://dota2lounge.com/match?m=13362 url it find 2 onclick selectTeam($(this), 'a') FUNCTIONS there.