# Python run JavaScript code while saving function definitions

Tags: python, node.js

I am building a python application that needs to run some javascript code. I have node.js installed. I want to define a function in javascript and then be able to run it elsewhere in the program. Here is an example:

```py
#My javascript function:
js_code = """
function add(a,b){return a+b};
"""
#Define js function here

myVar = add(3,4) #run the add function here
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Executing Javascript from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136319/executing-javascript-from-python)

Comment: @SuperStormer I am using python 3.8 and PyV8 is not in python 3.x.