# NodeJS on Python : AssertionError: Could not install the required module: fs

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

i'm trying to run javascript on my python script and i got this error :  **Could not install the required module: fs**

here is my small python script :

```
import js2py

context = js2py.EvalJs(enable_require=True)

code1 = '''
var fs = require('fs');
var File = fs.readFileSync('C:\\Users\\SAMSUNG\\Dropbox\\SB.crx', 'base64');
console.log(File);
'''
context.execute(code1)
```

Already installed it by terminal using : npm install fs

and got this :

```
(venv) C:\Users\SAMSUNG\PycharmProjects\test>npm install fs 

npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\SAMSUNG\PycharmProjects\test\package.json' 

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\SAMSUNG\PycharmProjects\test\package.json' 

npm WARN babelify@10.0.0 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. 

npm WARN test No description npm WARN test No repository field. 

npm WARN test No README data 

npm WARN test No license field. 

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\fsevents):

 npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ fs@0.0.1-security updated 1 package and audited 740 packages in 9.002s

4 packages are looking for funding   run `npm fund` for details

found 5 low severity vulnerabilities   run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Comment: `fs` is part of the standard Node.js library. You don't need to install it. What happens if you try to run your code without installing?

Comment: @ATOMP When i run the script i got this :
    AssertionError: Could not install the required module: fs

Comment: @ATOMP when i run on terminal i got this error : AssertionError : Could not link required node_modules

Comment: @mouadseghini Try this https://github.com/PiotrDabkowski/Js2Py/issues/125

Comment: @PrasannaBrabourame already tried that solution, it didn't work for me

Comment: @mouadseghini I just tried on my computer it tried to download `fs` from npm too. Seems like it's an issue with `py2js`. Hopefully it didn't execute any malware...probably should be doing this in a VM.

Comment: @ATOMP aah okayy, do you know any alternatives on how can i execute js code in my python script ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136319/executing-javascript-from-python