# Python request.get(URL) does not lead to a redirect although there's a redirect when trying in the browser

Tags: python, python-requests, html-parsing

There's this site called https://coolors.co and I want to grab the color palettes they generate programmatically. In the browser, I just click the button "Start the generator!". The link the button is attached to is https://coolors.co/generate. If I go to that url in the browser, the color palette is generated. Notice, that the url is changed to https://coolors.co/092327-0b5351-00a9a5-4e8098-90c2e7 (that's an example - the last part of the url is just the hex codes). There is obviously a redirect.

But when I do this in Python with a get request, I am not redirected but stay on this intermediate site. When I look at r.text, it tells me "This domain doesn't exist and is for sale".

How do I fix this? How do I enable the redirect?

Here's the code:

```
url = 'https://coolors.co/generate'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Thanks!

Comment: i'm not getting the message you're mentioning `This domain doesn't exist and is for sale`

Answer (score 0):

This website does not use an HTTP redirect.

It probably uses a Javascript form of redirection like changing `window.location.href`, requests is not a browser so it does not execute the javascript in the page you requested hence the absence of redirection.

Comment: Can I somehow trigger that javascript?

Comment: The simple answer is no, the complicated one is you should not but you could look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136319/executing-javascript-from-python.